Get-WmiObject access is denied, unauthorized access exception
Following a Windows update on Computer B, the following failed.
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "ComputerB"
With the error:
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:1
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName ComputerB

CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    
FullyQualifiedErrorId: System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

I launch the above from Computer A to query Computer B which returns the above error.
Both computers are on the same subnet and each FireWall is OFF.
I suspect, this is a DCOM\WinRM setting error.

The account that run that command must have access to the remote computer.
Are these computers in a domain or a workgroup is my main question here.
Try from one computer to naviguate to \computerAorB\c$, if it ask for a password you have an account permission problem.

Both Computers are in the same "domain". I can browse ComputerA\C$ and ComputerB\c$ both ways withe same domain\mylogin

You may want to run the winrm ping test or Test-WSMan to confirm that part is working.

Test-WSMan ComputerB returns the following. wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd
ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation
ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
